# Select with multi condition in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to search a `student` with multi condition in SQL, ex: `name`, `age`. But we may have only name or only age value or we may have all value with the information from user . I use a form in `HTML` to get values. I don't know how to write the query to select if they not fill all text field .

If I have only name value the query is

```
SELECT * FROM stuTBL WHERE name = @name
```

If I have only `age` value the query is

```
SELECT * FROM stuTBL WHERE age = @age
```

If I have all value the query is

```
SELECT * FROM stuTBL WHERE name = @name AND age = @age
```

But what query will cover whatever user input ?

Comment: You can use `LIKE` instead of `=` (need to escape `%` and `_`) and when you have no value for something you put in `%` (although the other solution is probably better, unless you want some more control).

Comment: Typically: `WHERE (age = @age or @age is null) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@austin wernli comment is one answer and I found another way to use that

SELECT * FROM stuTBL WHERE 
(name = @name or @name is null)
AND (age = @age or @age is null)

Comment: `@name = null` won't work, you should use `@name is null`

Comment: @Arulkumar thank , you are right

Answer (score 0):

Check the `@name = ''` , `@age = ''` along with the condition. If the `@name` is empty it will check the age condition only. If `@age` is empty it will check the name condition only.

If the both param have valid data then both the condition will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM stuTBL 
WHERE (name = @name OR ISNULL(@name, '') = '')
      AND (age = @age OR ISNULL(@age, '') = '')
```

Comment: it gives you result when there is user name and age present or not but not gives result when age is missing

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad : If age value is null or empty, `ISNULL(@age, '') = ''` is true. so obviously it will return data related to `name` condition

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad that depends on what value is used for `@age` when it is missing.

Comment: couldn't you simply that to read `WHERE name = ISNULL(@name, name) AND age = ISNULL(@age, age)`

Comment: @ austin wernli you are right, thank all

Comment: @austinwernli it would probably work, but I am always wary of putting field values in functions in `WHERE` (or `JOIN`) conditions as it is prone to ignoring indexes that might be present (though `OR` causes that alot too, so the concern may be moot in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
CASE name
    WHEN name = (@name OR @name = '')
CASE age 
    WHEN age = (@age OR @age = '')
END
FROM stuTBL
```

Comment: Is there actually an RDBMS where this would not result in a syntax error?

Comment: @TabAlleman Is there any language at all where this would be valid?